# Lua up-value issue for function in table

Tags: lua, upvalue

I am trying to create parts of tables many times but with different arguments. To do so, I have created a new function that takes a parameter, which is then used in a function in the table. My IDE shows the use of the parameter *value* inside the function as an "Up-value" problem.

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality without that issue?

```
function createTable(value)
    myTable = {
        name = 'Table',
        args = {
            time = 0,
            score = {
                function()
                    return value / 2
                end
            },
        },
    }
    return myTable
end
```

Comment: Your function returns a constant. Could just make that `score = value / 2` and avoid the function? Upvalues aren't a "problem", they are a legitimate feature of Lua.

Comment: What exactly should the function return?  A constant?

Comment: I'm quite sure your IDE does not show you "an up-value problem". if you get an error message, quote it. don't put into your own words discarding 90% of the information

Comment: I see that my example while simpler might not have been exactly equal to what I want. What my function actually should return is some value in table such as myTable[value].health